# error while launching apache Phoenix service

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I have installed apache-phoenix-4.10.0-HBase-1.2-bin.tar on my cloudera ready VM(cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.10.0-0-virtualbox), and I think that I am able to launch the phoenix command line prompt by executing the below query from phoenix bin dir

```
sudo ./sqlline.py localhost
```

After executing the above script, I can see something like as below

```
0:jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase>
```

So, I believe that the phoenix is working to some extent.However, I can see multiple error, when I scroll up in the messages that I see before the phoenix prompt is launched.

```
Error:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RtriesExhaustedException:Failed after attemptss=36, excepions:
java.net.sockettimeoutException:calltimeout=60000, callDuration=68699: row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG',,on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.15, seqNum=0(state=0)
```

I got below link, but I do not think, it has anything to do with my issue

```
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/java-net-SocketTimeoutException-on-table-hbase-meta-at-region/td-p/45074

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_scanner_heartbeat.html
```

However, I tried to ignore the issue, and continued with my working with Phoenix, but when I tried some operations in the phoenix command prompt, I am getting error

following are couple of Phoenix command I tried:
1) !tables
2) !list

for both of them I am getting

```
"no current connection"
```

I am not sure, but I have a feeling that because of the main error that I get before the phoenix prompt is launched is causing this. may be I am wrong.
I need guidance.

hbase version is 1.2

Adding the JPS output::

[cloudera@quickstart bin]$ sudo jps

```
7225 HistoryServer
5439 NameNode
15176 SqlLine
6746 RunJar
5701 Bootstrap
8072
5840 NodeManager
11057 SqlLine
5239 DataNode
10591 SqlLine
7201 Bootstrap
5169 QuorumPeerMain
15394 Main
7817 Bootstrap
15575 SqlLine
13309 SqlLine
15924 Jps
6835 RunJar
6053 ResourceManager
5335 JournalNode
6552 ThriftServer
5573 SecondaryNameNode
5757 JobHistoryServer
8114
8048 Bootstrap
13872 HMaster
6336 RESTServer
```

Comment: I've had this happen with virtualbox where I have to restart HBase Master.  check to see it's running.

Comment: echo mntr|nc localhost 2181
zk_version      3.4.5-cdh5.10.0--1, built on 01/20/2017 20:10 GMT
zk_avg_latency  0
zk_max_latency  102
zk_min_latency  0
zk_packets_received     12743
zk_packets_sent 12900
zk_num_alive_connections        3
zk_outstanding_requests 0
zk_server_state standalone
zk_znode_count  727
zk_watch_count  21
zk_ephemerals_count     3
zk_approximate_data_size        2611746
zk_open_file_descriptor_count   25
zk_max_file_descriptor_count    4096

Comment: echo mntr|nc localhost 2181
zk_version      3.4.5-cdh5.10.0--1, built on 01/20/2017 20:10 GMTzk_num_alive_connections        3
zk_outstanding_requests 0
zk_server_state standalone
zk_znode_count  727
zk_watch_count  21

so, I guess that my zookeeper is running

Comment: I can see that Hmaster is running

Comment: maybe a restart?

Comment: I have done everything that I cud, but no success

Comment: try connecting to localhost:2181

Comment: also maybe localhost:2181/hbase